# How to deliver email attachments to message on NodeJs using Express, Jade, Imap

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug, mime

I'm currently developing email client to our NodeJs application.

I got everything working, (List messages, open message etc..), except attachments.

**How I should deliver attachments** to page so **'cid:someId'** source will render it to correct place.

I tried to google how to work with cid sources without understanding how to use them.

I can see message attachments on NodeJs like this:

```
attachments: [  
    {   
        contentType: 'image/jpg',
        filename: "somePicture.jpg",    
        contents: ""                  //BASE64 string
        cid: 'someId'
    }   
]
```

**mailer.js**

```
var Mailer = function() {
     this.getMessages = function(cb) {

         ------ IMAP MESSAGES READ ------
             cb(messages);
         ------ IMAP MESSAGES READ ------

     };
     this.getMessage = function(seqNo, cb) {

         ------ IMAP MESSAGE READ ------
             cb(messages);
         ------ IMAP MESSAGE READ ------

     };
};

module.exports = new Mailer();
```

**router.js**

```
var mailer = require('./mailer');

app.get('/mailer', function(req, res) {
    var data = { title: 'Mailer' };
    mailer.getMessages(function(messages) {
        data.messages = messages;
        res.render('index', data);
    });
});

app.get('/message/:seqNo', function(req, res) {
    mailer.getMessage(req.param.seqNo, function(message) {
        res.render('message', {message: message);
    });
});
```

**index.jade**

```
html
    head
        script(type='text/javascript', src='main.js')
    body
        div
            each message in messages
               div(id=message.seqNo)
                   header
                       p= message.from
                       p= message.to
                       p= message.subject
                   div.content
                       p= message.message
```

**message.jade**

```
 !{message.html}
```

Produces something like:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        --- some content ---
        <img src='cid:someId' />
        --- some content ---
    </body>
</html>
```

Developer tool on Chrome, I see cid: Request

```
Name cid:someid
Method GET
Status (failed)
Initiator (index):1
Size 0 B
Time 2ms
```

And header show

```
General
  Request URL: cid:someId

Request Headers
  Provisional headers are shown
  Accept:image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
  Referer:http://localhost:5000/
  User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Are you using nodemailer?

Comment: Nope, Is it for sending emails?

Comment: [Yeah, here's a link](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer). Your implementation seems to be trying to load from the `cid`, but it's my understanding that the email service handles the `cid <--> path/content` mapping when inlining attachments. If you insist on building it yourself, might be helpful to take a look at how nodemailer does it.

Comment: Does nodemailer has option to use imap to read messages? I want to use our email client also to read emails on our application so no need for external email application at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're making a direct request to cid:someId without the server or browser knowing what to do with that protocol.

If all you need is rendering, you could parse the message and inject the content before you serve it. For example:

```
var message = "<img src='panda.jpg' /><img src='cid:someId' />";

function fetchContent(cid) {
  // Lookup goes here
  // return actual content url or base64 content, which will render
  return '/pictures/dog.png';
}
var result = message.replace(/('|")(cid:.*?)('|")/g, fetchContent('$1'));
```

which will return

```
<img src='panda.jpg' /><img src=/pictures/dog.png />
```